# Determine which value was selected

Tags: ruby, algorithm, logic

I have three numerical variables: `on_the_ground`, `double_round_trip` and `point_to_point`. The `price` function returns one of these based on some simple logic.

Below is how it currently works.

```
def price
  return on_the_ground if date_range == 1

  values = [
    on_the_ground,
    double_round_trip
  ]

  if !turbo? && !vlj?
    values.push(point_to_point)
  end

  values.compact.min
end
```

I'd like to have a function that can return a symbol based on which value should be returned. For example:

```
def price_name
  return :on_the_ground if date_range == 1
  ... etc...
end
```

Comment: A method can return a `Symbol`, just like the `price_name` method above does. What exactly is the issue?

Comment: I need to get the name of the variable that `values.compact.min` chose.

Comment: To do that you need a mapping between values and names. Use `Hash` to do that.

Answer (score 0):

If I get your point, why not use an array?

```
def price_name_for date_range
  [:on_the_ground, :double_round_trip, :point_to_point][date_range-1]
end

price_name_for 1 #=> :on_the_ground
price_name_for 2 #=> :double_round_trip
price_name_for 3 #=> :point_to_point
```

Comment: It's a little more complicated than that. There are some conditions for the point to point price to be in the array. I've provided an answer below showing how I solved it.

Answer (score -1):

you could use case

```
case values
  when double_round_trip
    return :double_round_trip
  when on_the_ground 
...
```

https://www.rubyguides.com/2015/10/ruby-case/

Answer (score -1):

I ended up using:

```
price_options.key(price) # double_round_trip
```

Comment: Using a `Hash` is what I suggested in my comment.